# Dynamic form creation and processing

Tags: django, django-forms

I have three models:

```
class Person( models.Model ):
    username = models.CharField( max_length=10 ) 
    name = models.CharField( max_length=10 ) 

class Category( models.Model ):
    catname = models.CharField( max_length=10 )

class Activity( models.Model ):
    person = models.ForeignKey( Person )
    category = models.ForeignKey( Category )
    value = models.FloatField( )
```

[updated question]

What I would like is a table of FloatFields where the columns are Category and rows are Person.

I can't seem to figure out how to create a table of FloatFields. If I create a list of self.fields[xx] = FloatField() then I (obviously) just get a long list of FloatFields. I could try and do some fancy table work in the template to get the FloatFields in a table format, but there has to be a better way to do this.

Comment: I'm guessing that the user is creating the category with "category(X)" , and that their will be multiple category fields that need to be processed at the same time? If so, reply to this and I will post my answer.

Comment: That is the case, exactly. I think I am confused by 1) how to prepopulate fields that have an Activity existing [vs new] and 2) how to keep track of each input's person and category and how to map back to the view for processing.

Comment: Have you tried to iterate over a range(X, Y) and get the value like this

Comment: @JodyFitzpatrick , could you elaborate on that?  I can't figure out how to make a table of FormFields in the template.